# Desmarcar CheckBox Somente Com Senha

Tags: delphi, object-pascal

Tenho um sistema e em uma parte preciso que somente membros do suporte possam desmarcar um checkbox.

Já Tentei diversos códigos mas sempre ocorre o mesmo problema : O CheckBox por padrão quando clicado ele é marcado ou desmarcado e eu não consegui achar uma maneira de parar esse processo e somente dar continuidade com a senha.

Último Código que tentei :

```
procedure TFEncerramentoPeriodo.CBFinanceiroClick(Sender: TObject);
var senha,senhad : String;
begin
senha := '328Cont';
 if CBFinanceiro.Checked = true then
 begin
   if not(InputQuery('Digite a Senha', 'Senha', Senhad))
  then
  exit;

    if (SenhaD=Senha) then
    begin
      CBFinanceiro.Checked := False;
    end
    else
    begin
      ShowMessage('Senha Incorreta! Somente Membros do Suporte Podem Desmarcar Essa Opção!');
      CBFinanceiro.Checked := True;
    end;
 end
```

Pesquisei em vários locais e inclusive aqui no SO e não achei ninguém com a mesma duvida ou problema igual ou parecido.

Comment: Independente da senha, num código convencional, como você faz para o checkbox ser somente leitura?

Comment: propriedade Enabled....

Comment: o que acontece é o seguinte, eu quero que o usuário possa habilitar o check box, mas nao possa desabilitá-lo sem antes contatar o suporte. Pois com esse formulário provocara uma reação em cadeia em outros formulários, alterando a maneira de como eles funcionarão

Comment: Bom, nada impede de habilitar se estiver unchecked, e desabilitar ao checar. Se tiver sucesso, poste como resposta no campo abaixo. Lembre-se que vc pode [edit] o post para melhorar. Aprender a fazer um [mcve] é importante também. Este link pode ajudar no melhor aproveitamento do site: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70)

Comment: okay, vou bolar um esquemaa! obrigado pelas dicas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui fazer com este código, utilizando os eventos OnMouseDown e OnKeyDown do CheckBox:

```
procedure TForm3.CheckBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  senha, senhad: string;
  b: boolean;
begin
  senha := '328Cont';
  if CheckBox1.Checked then
  begin
    b := InputQuery('Digite a senha', 'Senha', Senhad);
    CheckBox1.Checked := not (b and (senhad = senha));
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.CheckBox1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
var
  senha, senhad: string;
  b: boolean;
begin
  if Key <> VK_SPACE then
    exit;
  Key := 0;
  senha := '328Cont';
  if CheckBox1.Checked then
  begin
    b := InputQuery('Digite a senha', 'Senha', Senhad);
    CheckBox1.Checked := not (b and (senhad = senha));
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece-me que está a fazer o IF errado para a combo.
Quando tem a combo checkada e lá clica, ela entra nesse método já com o checked=false e nao checked=true. Assim o seu codigo funciona se alterar para

```
if CBFinanceiro.Checked = false then
begin
  if not(InputQuery('Digite a Senha', 'Senha', Senhad)) then
     CBFinanceiro.Checked := true;
```

A unica coisa menos boa é que a caixa aparece unchecked quando a prompt aparece, mas depois fica bem... nao sei se é problema.